# Canvas SDK and server side OAuth (.net)

Tags: oauth, canvas, .net

I am attempting to connect our C# MVC application with Salesforce to use within Salesforce record pages (e.g. opportunity details) and a Visual force page.

Using the Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET I can authenticate and communicate with Salesforce successfully and I have the MVC application appearing both in a visual force page and standard opportunity page. I am using the oAuth webflow option (not signed request). The force.net toolkit is handling the server side processing of this.

I need to use the Canvas JavaScript SDK to communicate between our application and Salesforce (to access the context and refresh the Salesforce display). I cannot get this to work either by attempting to set the appropriate Javascript variables or by a second login from client side script.

Is it possible to create the client from scratch using the server side authentication token?  [This questions suggests yes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53403/unable-to-retrieve-context-in-canvas-app-when-authenticating-with-oauth?rq=1) but gives no details. When I try to do this the request fails in 'validateClient' with both the Sfdc.canvas.oauth.instanceId and Sfdc.canvas.oauth.targetOrigin being null. The source suggests thesshould be functions but there is nothing there.

This is all in a dev organisation at v34.